# Android - Automating user interaction with a website

Tags: java, android, html, web-services, automation

I'm participating on a college project with a group of friends. We are trying to help pharmacists who work in a nearby public hospital. I'm tasked with sending and getting information to [Medscape](https://reference.medscape.com/).

To be more specific, I have to use Medscape's tool called [Drug Interaction Checker](https://reference.medscape.com/drug-interactionchecker) to send a list of drugs and get an answer in pdf format.

For instance, given ibuprofen and nizoral I get this [answer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PYwEfUqNBvDSCUUXt7jafeVfNPVTd9W7/view?usp=sharing). You can test it yourself if you have 15 seconds to spare.

My problem is I don't know how to "simulate user input on the site". Can someone guide me in the right way?

---

I need the solution to:

- Be available in Android
- Work without any user interaction with the site. User has a list of predefined drugs and I want to get the output of the site and make something like a "risk score" and present it to him.

Comment: when you say no user interaction, who is going to provide the input? Do you want to create hardcoded examples just to showcase the tool functionality?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the user would not interact directly with the tool. I kinda need to make something like an API for my coleagues to use.
About the examples I can't provide that because I haven't started yet. But you could say I have a list of drugs and I want the output of the site for them.